# rails sql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have:

```
User id:integer name:integer
class User
has_many :complete_tasks
end

Task id:integer style:string uid:string

CompleteTask id:integer style:string uid:string user_id:integer
class CompleteTask
belongs_to :user
end
```

i have some records in DB

```
user = User.first
```

id:1 name:Den

```
tasks = Tasks.all
```

id:1 style => "run" uid => "river"

id:2 style => "jump" uid => "sea"

id:3 style => "run" uid =>"sea"

id:4 style => "run" uid =>"river"

id:5 style => "run" uid =>"forest"

```
user.complete_tasks.all
```

id:1 style => "run" uid => "river" user_id => 1

id:2 style => "jump" uid => "sea" user_id => 1

How to get records from Task where fields :style and :uid together not equivalent fields :style and :uid in model CompleteTask.

Comment: what's the difference between the tasks with `id3` and `id5` compared to other ones?

Comment: I want to get all the records Task in which the fields :style and :uid      does not coincide with the fields :style and :uid in model CompleteTasks.

Comment: the only thing i am thinking of is making two each/for loops and comparing it like that. This is a really poor database model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a poor database model and i would recommend to use something else. Maybe a boolean value or smthng like that in the `task` model so you can check if it's complete or not.
Anyways, here is a solution:

```
all_tasks = Task.all
complete_tasks = CompleteTask.all

complete_tasks.each do |complete_task|
    #find if there is a task with the corresponding uid and style in the complete tasks
    tasks = all_tasks.where(:uid => complete_task.uid, :style => complete_task.style)
    #remove it from all_tasks (all_tasks means tasks that haven't finished yet)
    all_tasks = @all_tasks -  tasks
end

return all_tasks
```

Comment: Thanks, I will think how to do differently.

Comment: No problem, if you write how you are implementing everything maybe i could help you

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're trying to find all tasks that don't have the same IDs as complete tasks.

For that you should use a [find condition](http://railscasts.com/episodes/15-fun-with-find-conditions)--something like:

```
Task.find(:all, :conditions => { :complete => false });
```